# How to create an primary key in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, primary-key

I have two tables, the first one is called BOOKSNAME and the second is called AUTHORNAME.

I have made the ID column for the BOOKSNAME table as the primary key (BIGINT auto increment) then my AUTHORNAME table has NAME and ADDRESS as it's columns but I have no ID/Primary key on this.

I want to make a relation between them by primary key, if anyone has an example of how this is achieved, could they share it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need to do is add a new column to your AUTHORNAME table called AuthorID or something similar, you can select 'Primary' on a drop down list under the INDEX when adding a new column to your table, and you also want to tick the A_I box (auto increment).

If you are unsure how to add a new column, follow these steps:

Firstly go to your phpmyadmin, and select the table in which you need to add this new column/ primary key to, and select the structure tab.

Here you will see the current column headings that your table already has, so from here you want to look towards the bottom of that list of columns where it will display options on how to add a new column to your table.

Ideally, you want to add the ID at the beginning of the table, as it will make it look far more structured and easier to read.

From here you want to enter the name of the column, in your case AuthorID, the type will be an INT, and you will want to make your index as PRIMARY, then lastly you will need to tick the A_I / Auto increment box (This may appear differently depending on what version of phpmyadmin you are running).

If you then want to make relations between the two tables, you can use something called JOINS, if you do a simple Google search, you can find many guides on how these are carried out.

Answer (score 0):

Also add integer primary key to the author table, next you can have `author_id` field to another table, which is same datatype as authors table primary key, and store author id to that field.

Also if you use `Innodb` engine you can add foreign key constraint, it is very useful, for more see documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html